# Wordpress não lista posts corretamente

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou com um problema no WordPress, um cliente passou um tema pra eu instalar no WordPress, ele comprou e me passou, eu apenas joguei na pasta themes do WordPress. O que acontece é que quando lista os posts ele lista, só que exibe o conteúdo todo no post, as fotos do posts não aparecem certas, etc. [Olhem aqui](http://sitedainterage.com.br/wordpress/the-blog/), esse é o que eu instalei. Na página de compra do `theme` eles tem a [mesma página](http://www.mestowabo.com/theme/news-board/the-blog/) só que corretamente, como tem que ficar.

Comment: Você só pegou o tema e jogou na pasta **Themes** foi isso que entendi?

Comment: Na pasta do *tema* comprado tem alguma pasta de **images** ou **img** ou algo relacionado à imagens?

Comment: Sim, só coloquei lá, instalei os plugins que precisava de acordo com a documentação e ativei o tema. Dentro da pasta do tema tem a pasta "framework" e dentro dela tem as pastas de imagens, css, js, etc.

Comment: Então troque o endereço das imagens que está no tema pelo local em que está no seu diretório.

Comment: As imagens estão aparecendo certinho, mas pelo meu ver é algo com css, porque não está listando "bonitinho" e está exibindo todo o texto e não aparecendo "ler mais"

Comment: Veja se o tema não define campos especiais para o resumo do post e para as imagens que compoe o slider

Comment: O ver mais no wordpress nem sempre é automática, as vezes você precisa adicionar o ```<!--more-->``` para aparecer o ler mais. Outra coisa estranha nos titulos do post é que no site do vendedor eles são h4 com 13px no font-size e no seu eles são h5 com 18px no font-size. Outro problema para as imagens é que no seu site a div na qual elas estão e o conteúdo tem as classes "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" no vendedor tem as classes ```col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6``` e o conteúdo tem as classes ```col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6```, ou seja no seu cada div ocupa 12 colunas no dele uma ocupa 4 e a outra 8